# AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'public_flags'

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py, attributeerror

```
@commands.command()
async def profile(self, ctx, *, user: discord.Member = None):
    """Profile"""
    if user == None:
      user = ctx.author
    server = ctx.guild
    #error in this
    print(ctx.author.public_flags)
    #
    ..........
```

I want to know public flags of user example: Hypesquad balance

Comment: Have you tried using the most recent version of the discord.py library?

Comment: yes, i tried using the most recent version of the discord.py library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.**Install recent discord.py from github**

```
@commands.command()
async def profile(self, ctx, *, user: discord.Member = None):
    """Profile"""
    if user == None:
      user = ctx.author
    server = ctx.guild
    print(ctx.author.public_flags.all())
    ..........
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`discord.User.profile`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User.profile).

```py
@commands.command()
async def profile(self, ctx, *, user: discord.Member = None):
    """Profile"""
    if user == None:
      user = ctx.author
    server = ctx.guild
    # this for example prints if the user has discord nitro
    print(await ctx.author.profile().nitro)
```

Information a profile contains [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Profile)

Comment: 1. i use bot
2. When i use `await ctx.author.profile()` error `403 Forbidden `
3. When i use `await ctx.author.profile().nitro` error `AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'nitro'`

Comment: If you are getting the coroutine error, that means that you either have an outdated/too new python version or an outdated discord.py install. Try reinstalling both